# Indefinitely identifying the same user constantly in PHP

Tags: php, identification, user-identification

Let's cut to the chase:

I'm working on a social/personal site, and I need to be able to ban users from it if they break the rules.

I know I can identify a user by IP address to block them if they ARE banned, but what if they have a dynamic IP address like myself?

getbrowser()? Most computers and phones have more than 1 kind of web browser.

And what about proxies?

Is there any way to identify the same user over and over again with something that NEVER changes? I mean, a while back I thought I could do something to solve this issue.
I was thinking about:

```
 1. Get the IP of the user
 2. Get the country of the user
 3. Get the browser and OS of the user.
```

That is still too broad of a search. I could be blocking multiple people at once with a search like that.

How do these big websites like Twitter and Facebook do this? It's an absolute nightmare for me so far.

Aren't IP addresses supposed to be like a raffle ticket?
No 2 are alike at one time?
If that's true, I may be able to work something out.

Other than that, I'm stuck.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd just go with the IP, everything else can be changed as it is user input. If the IP is dynamic, you could try a subnet ban, but I'd go against it -- most people use vpns or proxies anyways.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to identify the same user over and over again with something that NEVER changes?

No, there isn't.

Comment: So if you're banned from say, Facebook, is there a method that they have to keep you from re-signing up for a new account?

Comment: @ricky: No, their only chance is that you don't have another email address to spoil :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't check the ip addresses etc. Just force user to log in and send the password to users email address. Then disable the account for a while if needed. This is the first step!